# How to fuzzy query a list?

Tags: database, oracle, entity-relationship

SELECT *

FROM table

WHERE column_one LIKE IN ('%one%', '%two%');

This will be error with : SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression

How to implement this kind of fuzzy query?

Comment: There is no way to do this with `IN`. You can do `WHERE column_one LIKE '%one%' OR column_one LIKE '%two%'` of course. Or have the patterns in a table and use an `EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course as commented the usage of `OR` is the *correct* way, though a bit *verbose*.

The most close option to *your* approach is the usage of `regexp_like` with a pattern allowing more alternatives.

*Example*

```
with tab as (
select '...one..' column_one from dual union all
select '.two.,..' column_one from dual union all
select '.three..' column_one from dual)
select *
from tab
where  regexp_like(column_one,'(one|two)'); 

COLUMN_O
--------
...one..
.two.,..
```

Answer (score 0):

You may generate lookup table and check it for every input row with `exists` predicate.

> ```
> create table t as
>   select
>     level as id
>     , decode(mod(level, 7), 1,'A', 'B')
>       || dbms_random.string('i', 10) as val
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 16
> ```

> ```
> with lkp(val) as (
>   select *
>   from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
>     'A%',
>     '%F%'
>   ))
> )
> select *
> from t
> where exists (
>   select 1
>   from lkp
>   where t.val like lkp.val
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | VAL        
> -: | :----------
>  1 | AJHCIHZIVQY
>  2 | BQCYACBBLFS
>  3 | BVATBIEQFEF
>  4 | BHEFYAUUENF
>  7 | BFPZVWRWTFP
>  8 | AGSKVEXPFSV
> 11 | BFSJXDRGAWV
> 14 | BFVXCSQWUQT
> 15 | AFJPPPHDTKM
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2a5d4eeea1436b4d5f63bbef8f38794b)*